# MathJax не обновляет формулу при её изменении

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, mathjax

Есть div, в который должна выводиться формула в зависимости от выбора пользователя в выпадающем списке. Для написания формул подключил Mathjax Написал код, однако вместо правильной формулы x=5 выдает $$x=5$$.

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', ChangeGraph);


function ChangeGraph() {
    page_formula.innerText = '$$x=5$$';
}

ChangeGraph();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ChangeGraph() {
        page_formula.innerText = formulas[graph_list.selectedIndex];
        MathJax.typeset();
}
```

Подробнее: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html#typesetting-math-in-a-web-page